# I am optimizing f(x) using scipy.optimize.minimize and the value of f(x) cannot be negative but scipy.optimize returns a min value as negative

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

The minimized function value of f(x) should be greater than or equal to 0. However, scipy.optimize.minimize provides a negative value of f(x). Is there any way we could put a constraint on the function value?

Comment: If your function can be negative, then I don't see why it's a problem that a *minimizer* finds a negative value. It's unclear why or what you want to constrain exactly: the function parameters, the function value (in which case: change the function to always return a positive value), or something else. Can you provide a (simplified) concrete example of your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve:

```
 min z
 z = f(x)
 z >= 0
```

However, nonlinearly constrained problems are often more difficult to solve than unconstrained or linearly constrained problems.

If the model is essentially a root finding problem (i.e. we can get very close to zero), you can try:

```
  min f(x)^2
```